# Maketrans not working for petl with python3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, petl

I am using petl package which i have installed using pip  in virtulaenv with python 3.4. when i tried to test that whether the petl package is installed properly or not in the python shell 
I have done this to check

```
$ python 
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from petl import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/.env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/petl/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from petl.util import header, fieldnames, data, records, rowcount, look, see, \
  File "/home/user/.env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/petl/util.py", line 14, in <module>
    from string import maketrans
ImportError: cannot import name 'maketrans'
>>>
```

I tried to check whether  maketrans is present in  string package i run this

```
>>> from string import maketrans
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'maketrans'
>>>
```

Found that the default python string package does not have this . I am not sure that why petl package have used this without mentioning it in its dependency and if its the default python package then why its giving import error.

Not sure what is happening can any one please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** [`petl >= 1.0` supports Python 3.4](http://petl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/changes.html#version-1-0).

---

Clearly [`petl`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/petl) does not work on Python 3.x.

This specific error is because the Python 2.x [`string.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans) function doesn't exist in 3.x.* But if you got past that, you'd find lots of other errors.

While the PyPI entry doesn't list supported versions (which it really should), a quick google turned up [Issue #240](https://github.com/alimanfoo/petl/issues/240), to add Python 3 support, which has been on the backlog since 26 Aug 2014. And a `2to3` pass over the source shows hundreds of issues.**

So, how do you fix this?

1. Use something other than `petl`.
2. Use Python 2.7 for your `petl` work.
3. Help port it.

<sub>* Actually, in 3.0, it still existed, but only worked on `bytes` objects. In 3.1, `maketrans` and `translate` methods were added to `bytes` and `bytearray`, equivalent to the ones on `str`, and the `string` functions were deprecated, and then in 3.2 or 3.3 they were removed.</sub>

<sub>** Some of these issues are using things that were already deprecated in 2.6 or 2.7, which is odd given that `petl` originally worked only in 2.7, and was later ported to also work in 2.6.</sub>

Answer (score 20):

In Python2, `maketrans` is a function belongs to the `string` module. However in Python3, `maketrans` is a static method of the `str` type.

Answer (score 10):

Because I was looking for a clear example of how it works in python 3.4, I post what I've found:

```
#in py2 you need to "from string import maketrans" 
table = "".maketrans('cs', 'kz')
#py2 table = maketrans('cs', 'kz')
len(table)
#in py2 you will get **len(table) = 256 in py3.4 len(table) = 2**
sentence = "cause koala is causing trouble"
sentence.translate(table)
```

Answer (score 9):

use **str** to invoke maketrans

```
LETTERS = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
NUMBERS = '22233344455566677778889999'
## translate a-z char to phone digits
TRANS = str.maketrans(LETTERS, NUMBERS)
```