# Install package from conda for a specific version of python

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda

I'm relatively new on dealing with python libraries so it might be a stupid question but here is the detailed problem:

I'm working on Linux and trying to use a python program (`ORF-rater`) using python 3.7. Unfortunately, when I run the program, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'maketrans' from 'string'
```

which I think is related to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27539884/maketrans-not-working-for-petl-with-python3-4). Therefore I want to use another version of Python (3.4 or 2.7 for instance) that will support this `maketrans`.

The program that I'm using also uses the Python package `plastid`, which I installed using Conda `conda install -c bioconda plastid` which I guess worked well.

However, it installed the package on python 3.7 only, and I can't find a way to install for python 3.4 (I tried others things as `pip3.4 install plastid`, but it did not work, most likely because I'm working on an university server and I don't have permission to do it).

### In brief, how do I install a package using Conda for a specific version of Python (3.4)?

Comment: Just a note; do *not* mix conda and pip. That only leads do disasters!

Comment: Can you be more exhaustive and explain why ?

Comment: The python environment can be "confused", so to speak, regarding what packages to use. from where. I did it once and it took ages to get python working again (I removed conda, pip and reinstalled python)

Comment: Thx, then, maybe that's why I'm not permitted to use ```pip``` on the university server^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code creates an environment with a specific python version (2.7 since [3.4 was not an option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56850972/why-conda-cannot-create-environment-with-python-3-4-installed-in-it)), then you activate it and install the package you need.

```
conda create -n test python=2.7
conda activate test 
conda install -c bioconda plastid
python
```

Then in Python, I did the following and got no errors

```py
from string import maketrans
```

Comment: It's always better to do it in one command: `conda create -n test -c conda-forge -c bioconda python=2.7 plastid` No reason to have the solver run twice.